Is there a way to make Ruby HTTPI use IPv6?
I have an existing test framework that uses Ruby's HTTPI library to make HTTP calls, and I'm trying to add a test for IPv6 (dual-stack) support.  The code looks something like this:
def http_get(request_url, request_headers)
  request = HTTPI::Request.new(request_url)
  request.headers = request_headers
  # TODO: how do I configure this to force IPv6?
  return HTTPI.get(request)
end

If the request_url supports both IPv4 and IPv6, is there some way to force HTTPI to use IPv6 to handle the request so I can verify that our IPv6 endpoint setup is working properly?

Did you try using an IPv6 address as the url?

But the point is that the URL I'm trying to reach is accessible over both IPv4 and IPv6...

Ultimately, any test of this sort is going to work by resolving the hostname into separate IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and trying to make requests to those individually. It doesn't look like HTTPI has this functionality built in.
Luckily, it's easy to do yourself using getaddrinfo. Here's an example of how to resolve www.google.com into an IPv6 address.
require 'socket'

addrinfos = Addrinfo.getaddrinfo("www.google.com", 80, nil, :STREAM)
ipv4_address = addrinfos.select(&:ipv4?).first&.ip_address
ipv6_address = addrinfos.select(&:ipv6?).first&.ip_address

# => "2607:f8b0:4006:81e::2004"

If ipv6_address is not nil (and for www.google.com, it is not), you can then rebuild your request_url by replacing the hostname with "[#{ipv6_address}]" (the square brackets are required), and then use that new URL in your http_get method.
If ipv6_address is nil, your test has successfully revealed that there's something wrong with your AAAA DNS record.

Thanks, this getaddrinfo is very useful.  Unfortunately, it seems like HTTPI doesn't understand IPv6 addresses?  I followed your example code, and then tried to do HTTPI.get(HTTPI::Request.new("http://#{ipv4_address}")) which worked fine with the IPv4 address, but then I tried HTTPI.get(HTTPI::Request.new("http://#{ipv6_address}")) with the IPv6 address and I got this error: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://2607:f8b0:400a:800::2004"  (It also fails if I remove the http://)

@Dasmowenator The square brackets are required when using an IPv6 address in a url. So "http://[2607:f8b0:400a:800::2004]" is what you would need to use. See paragraph 3 above.

Ah, I see... though now I'm getting a different error:
Sending request to: http://[2607:f8b0:400a:806::2004]
Results in this error: Failed to open TCP connection to [2607:f8b0:400a:806::2004]:80 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

@Dasmowenator You may not be able to reach Google via ipv6. It turns out I can't. See https://superuser.com/questions/335639/how-do-i-properly-access-google-through-ipv6 , and following one of their suggestions, visit ipv6-test.com in your browser. Some part of my stack apparently has ipv6 disabled. It could be my machine, my network, or my ISP. You might be in the same situation. If so, then depending on which part of your stack it is, you may not be able to conduct your test until you have IPv6 enabled throughout.
